# Recommended hardware specifications for installing SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013

I'd like to install **SharePoint Designer 2013** and I've done some hunting around but I can't for the life of me find:

1. The ***minimum*** hardware specification
2. The ***recommended*** hardware specification

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best info there is:

- Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012
- Microsoft .NET 4.0 Framework or higher

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491

A lot of times you don't get spefics for RAM, CPU, etc. for client side applications.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you will get more information besides this:

> Supported Operating System
>
> Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012
>
> - Microsoft .NET 4.0 Framework or higher

[from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491).

All other information you will get will be based on peoples personal opinions.